# How to change a categorical factor levels to numeric variable in R

Tags: r

[image]

I have a pid factor variable with 195 levels that I would like to change to a numeric variable per unique patient id. Can anyone assist with that?TIA below is how my data looks like;
[image]

Comment: Did you try `as.numeric`/`as.integer` on the factor variable?

Answer (score 1):

When you transform the factor to numeric with `as.numeric()` R doesn't use the labels that you see but the factor levels. If you have the factor `as.factor(c(1,2,5,7))` for example, the levels are still 1,2,3,4 as in 1st category, 2nd category, 3rd category & 4th category. The easiest way to use the actual labels is to transform the factor to a character string first and then transform the character string to a numeric variable.

```
 NewVariable <- as.numeric(as.character(FactorVariable))
```

Comment: Please when you answer to a question provide always an explanation